# SharePoint Online List Minor Versions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, versioning

I have a requirement that SharePoint Lists should require Content Approval. Draft versions of the List entries should undergo Workflow Approval first before users with lesser permissions (Ex. Read) be able to see them.

I had no problem doing this for our Doc Libraries. However, for this List, I noticed that there is no option for Lists for Minor Versions?

Am I missing something or it is really not supported? And if it is not supported, are there alternatives I can do to do the same function as the above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as per [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-does-versioning-work-in-a-list-or-library-05ac5f92-4b19-4a47-80ac-3f9e232bb8c3#__toc270599846):

- Simple versioning is available **for site lists**, but **minor versions are not available**. Each version of a list item is numbered with a whole
  number. If your organization requires approval of items in a list,
  the items remain in Pending status until they are approved by someone
  who has permissions to approve them. While in Pending status they are
  numbered with whole numbers and **are referred to as drafts**.

But your business requirement will work fine without minor versions:

When `Create a version each time you edit an item in this list?` is set to `Yes`:

- `Keep the following number of versions` is always active.
- `Keep drafts for the following number of approved versions` will get active only after you first set `Require content approval for submitted items?` to `Yes`.

When `Create a version each time you edit an item in this list?` is set to `No`, both are disabled for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks Aziz! I checked and yes, it seems that limited users won't be able to see a change undergoing the Approval (even if it is marked as 2.0). Was confused when comparing with working in Doc Libs.